# why is the value being automatically assigned to new_element in the following code

Tags: python

```
class node:

   def __init__(self,data):
       self.data = data
       self.next = None

class ll():

    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None


    def append(self,*argv):
        for data in argv:
            new = self.head
            if self.head:
                while new:
                    new = new.next
                new = node(data)
            else:
                self.head = node(data)

    def read(self):
        alpha = self.head
        while alpha:
            print(alpha.data)
            alpha = alpha.next

def main():
    a = ll()
    a.append("a","h","j","k")
    a.read()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**problem 1:**

Initially `self.head` has `None` as value , thus it assigns `None` value to the `new` variable.

Therefore I expect an error saying none type object has no attribute next, which i donot get. while another thing here is that while loop (while new). Here it should assign a new node to new.next and then so on but when i try to print it , it says `self.head.next` i.e. `alpha.next` is None type and thus the while alpha loop is exited and i only get a printed  on the screen. i am unable to understand that why is `new.next` is not being assigned the `node ("h")`

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `self.head` which is `None` to the variable `new` at the start, but in the next line `if self.head` ensures that it should not run for the first time. Because `self.head` is `None` and the condition is evaluated to `False` the while loop will not be executed for the first iteration and in the second one `new` will have a valid non-none value.

Coming to your second problem you have to change you while loop to following to get all the results:

```
if self.head:
            while new.next: # We have to stop when after a node there is None.
                new = new.next
            new.next = node(data) # Now add the new data at the end.
```

Comment: in the second part this exactly is my doubt, why only this code but not mine is working. what i expect is when new is assigned already  the address of a node then it should run the loop and change new to new.next and reach this situation as you proposed but this is not happening. then why is it not  happening since my code must eventually reach this situation. or am i missing something

Comment: let's look at this condition `while new: new=new.next` this loop will exit when new is `None` or the list is ended. And now `new=node(data)`  is assigning a new value to `new`. So as you can see there is no link between the original list and the new value. You have to add your new data to list.

Comment: in the working case we have new1.next (say new2)  (just representation). then since new2 is None it will assign node to new1.next which is new2 while in my case the new1 since filled be bypassed and new2 will be arrived and then assignment will occur at new2 at the end both should be same.... sorry but still a doubt

Comment: Let's take a simple example of a linked list `1-> 2-> None`. So `new` is like an empty box in which first node with value 1 was put, then 2 and then None. When it was None you filled it with `node(data)`. At this point linked list is not changed because `new` has no connection to the linked list. But in the correct case we stopped when `new` has node with value 2, so here while assigning the value to `new` you actually assigned some value to the node in the linked list.